# Loop is not working with the Intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, firebase, twitter

I'm creating a Twitter bot using Firebase and Twitter API to unfollow the inactive accounts.

This was the Nodejs code:

```
// Get the screen_names in `to_unfollow` table
firebase.database().ref("to_unfollow/" + settings.PERSON_TWITTER_HANDLE).on("value", function(snapshot) {

// Functional Loop
var i = 0;
function timedLoop() { // unFollows the user after every `x` seconds

      /*=============================================>>>>>
      = Thing to be done =
      ===============================================>>>>>*/

        function snapshotToArray(snapshot) { // This function converts the Snapshot data into an array
            var returnArr = [];

            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var item = childSnapshot.val();
                item.key = childSnapshot.key;

                returnArr.push(item);
            });

            return returnArr;
        };

        var screen_name_to_unfollow = snapshotToArray(snapshot)[i].key;

        console.log(screen_name_to_unfollow);

      /*= End of Thing to be done =*/
      /*=============================================<<<<<*/

      // Increase value of variable `i` by 1. (Increment)
      i++;

      // How many times to loop
      if(i < 5000) {
          setTimeout( timedLoop, 1000*20 ); // timedLoop();
      }

  }

  timedLoop(); // Run the loop

});
```

Here, my loop worked very well. The `screen_name_to_unfollow` variable was logged into the console after every 20 seconds.

---

But when I add the executive code to unfollow people, loop works... but not with a time interval. It just keeps unfollowing people.

Here's how my code seems to be after:

```
// Get the screen_names in `to_unfollow` table
firebase.database().ref("to_unfollow/" + settings.PERSON_TWITTER_HANDLE).on("value", function(snapshot) {

// Functional Loop
var i = 0;
function timedLoop() { // unFollows the user after every `x` seconds

      /*=============================================>>>>>
      = Thing to be done =
      ===============================================>>>>>*/

        function snapshotToArray(snapshot) { // This function converts the Snapshot data into an array
            var returnArr = [];

            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var item = childSnapshot.val();
                item.key = childSnapshot.key;

                returnArr.push(item);
            });

            return returnArr;
        };

        var screen_name_to_unfollow = snapshotToArray(snapshot)[i].key;

        console.log(screen_name_to_unfollow);

        // UnFollow
        T.post('friendships/destroy', { screen_name: screen_name_to_unfollow },  function (err, data, response) {
          console.log('T.Post', new Date());
          if(!err){
            console.log(settings.PERSON_NICKNAME + " follower " + screen_name_to_unfollow + " unfollowed.");

            // Create an `unfollowed` table and insert the screen_name there
            firebase.database().ref("unfollowed").child(settings.PERSON_TWITTER_HANDLE).update({
              [screen_name_to_unfollow]: {
                connection: "unfollowed"
              }
            });

            // Delete the screen_name from `to_unfollow` table
            firebase.database().ref("to_unfollow/" + settings.PERSON_TWITTER_HANDLE).child(screen_name_to_unfollow).remove();

          } else{
            console.log(err);
          }
        });

      /*= End of Thing to be done =*/
      /*=============================================<<<<<*/

      // Increase value of variable `i` by 1. (Increment)
      i++;

      // How many times to loop
      if(i < 5000) {
          setTimeout( timedLoop, 1000*20 ); // timedLoop();
      }

  }

  timedLoop(); // Run the loop

});
```

In the terminal, you can see that intervals didn't work out.

```
T.Post 2018-05-31T02:11:27.234Z
Wesbos follower AnnSaid unfollowed.
T.Post 2018-05-31T02:11:27.914Z
Wesbos follower AnnyShivang unfollowed.
T.Post 2018-05-31T02:11:28.865Z
Wesbos follower AntJanus unfollowed.
T.Post 2018-05-31T02:11:29.888Z
Wesbos follower AnthonyCatonPR unfollowed.
T.Post 2018-05-31T02:11:30.975Z
Wesbos follower AppleLaa unfollowed.
T.Post 2018-05-31T02:11:31.733Z
Wesbos follower AsyrafDuyshart unfollowed.
```

**What can I do in this situation to make the loop work as it worked before?** I want unfollow handful of inactive twitter accounts after every 20 seconds because I don't want to fall in rate limit.

**Thanks in advance :-)**

Comment: What is the exact problem? does `T.post` throws any error?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande T.post throws no errors. but the loop doesn't work with the time interval..

Comment: `timedLoop` only runs once, or ir never runs?

Comment: works continously as wanted. but not after every 20 seconds. it just keeps unfollowing the people.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: it just keeps unfollowing the people. Don't you want it to unfollow people, it tries to unfollow the same person twice, or what is the actual problem?

Comment: No, I want it to unfollow. But with an interval of 20seconds. after every 20 seconds, i should increment and the next person should be unfollowed. But here, the T.post works without any interval of 20seconds. T.post is only what I mean by unfollowing. Noob words. Sorry for that

Comment: I doubt that, please put this inside `T.post`, `console.log('T.Post', new Date());` and show us the output, according to you, this happens multiple times in 20 seconds.

Comment: Sure :-) Will do that now

Comment: Done. added and logged the dates and edited the question. Do take a look :-)

Comment: Ok, I know the answer.

Comment: yeah sure, i m waiting

Comment: You can check it now, let me know.

Comment: thanks, it worked :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `.on` listener of firebase, is being called every time `T.post` ends, since you're removing from `to_unfollow/`.

So every time `T.post` ends, you're creating an additional `setTimeout` loop, and if you let that code run for some minutes, you will performing thousands of requests to twitter.

Using `.once` instead will fix your problem. And after all users from the snapshot are unfollowed, you should request another set to firebase.

Comment: It gotta be it, even though I never used firebase :)

Comment: I not understood by what you meant with `And after all users from the snapshot are unfollowed, you should call request another set to firebase.`

Comment: Once that snapshot is processed, you may have more users to unfollow, you should call: `firebase.database().ref("to_unfollow/" + settings.PERSON_TWITTER_HANDLE).once` again to see if there are more

Comment: I had a typo, `you should request another set to firebase`